# Pull rows that are matching certain criteria and save as a new CSV file with Pandas/Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm looking for a robust way to pull rows that match certain criteria in the name column to a new CSV file. My file has thousands of rows and new rows are being added everyday and I'm looking to pull rows that:

- have duplicated name (if same name occurs more than once then move all rows with same name to new.csv)
- have a single word that is longer than 15 characters
- have registration title string included within name: 'LLC', '.INC', 'inc' etc. (no matter if upper or lowercase)
- have total character count greater than 15
- have url listed as name have numeric values only listed as a name

my.csv

```
id    name                            url                                   phone
1     ACME                            http://www.someurl.com               +44123456789
2     http://www.someurl.com          http://www.someurl.com               +44123456789
3     longsinglewordname              http://www.someurl.com               +44123456789
4     long multiple words name        http://www.someurl.com               +44123456789
5     ACME                            http://www.someurl.com               +44123456789
6     acme                            http://www.someurl.com               +44123456789
7     CMEA LLC                        http://www.someurl.com               +44123456789
8     CMEA lLC                        http://www.someurl.com               +44123456789
9     Correct Name                    http://www.someurl.com               +44123456789
10    12345                           http://www.someurl.com               +44123456789
11    Correct Name2                   http://www.someurl.com               +44123456789
```

In my output I'm aiming to list all rows that match my criteria with additional column 'issue' to highlight what criteria have been met. Each row can have multiple criteria. See row 2 (url, longWord). Currently I don't know how to implement this bit into my code. Could someone help?

desired new.csv:

```
id    name                            url                                   phone         issue
1     ACME                            http://www.someurl.com               +44123456789    dupe
2     http://www.someurl.com          http://www.someurl.com               +44123456789    url
                                                                                           longWord
3     longsinglewordname              http://www.someurl.com               +44123456789    longWord
4     long multiple words name        http://www.someurl.com               +44123456789    longMultiple
5     ACME                            http://www.someurl.com               +44123456789    dupe
6     acme                            http://www.someurl.com               +44123456789    dupe
7     CMEA LLC                        http://www.someurl.com               +44123456789    regTitle
8     CMEA lLC                        http://www.someurl.com               +44123456789    regTitle
10    12345                           http://www.someurl.com                +44123456789   numericVal
```

my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("path/to/my.csv")

df1 = pd.concat(g for _, g in df.groupby("name") if len(g) > 1)

#below im trying to get only numeric values within name column but it fails 'Invalid syntax' and pointing at exclamation mark !str_detect
df2 = df[!str_detect(df$name,("([0-9])")),]   

#not sure what would be the best way to differentiate count for single words & multiple words
df3 = df[df['name'].apply(lambda x: len(str(x)) > 15)]  

df4 = #not sure how to recognize that string has string+'.xxx' or string+'.xx'


#not sure if this is the best way to save/append my results
df1.to_csv('/path/to/my/new.csv', index = False)
df2.to_csv('/path/to/my/new.csv', mode='a', index = False)
df3.to_csv('/path/to/my/new.csv', mode='a', index = False)
df4.to_csv('/path/to/my/new.csv', mode='a', index = False)
```

Any help is welcome. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your conditions are pretty straight forwards, just do:

```
duplicates=df['name'].str.lower().duplicated(keep=False)
longtitles = df['name'].str.len() > 15        # this includes single word > 15 chars already

# updated with word boundary
contains = df['name'].str.contains(fr"\b{'|'.join(['LLC','inc'])}\b",
                                   re.IGNORECASE)

numerics = df['name'].str.match('^\d+$')
urls = df['name'].str.match('https?://')

# output
df[duplicates|longtitles|contains|numerics|urls]
```

Output:

```
   id                      name                     url         phone
0   1                      ACME  http://www.someurl.com  +44123456789
1   2    http://www.someurl.com  http://www.someurl.com  +44123456789
2   3        longsinglewordname  http://www.someurl.com  +44123456789
3   4  long multiple words name  http://www.someurl.com  +44123456789
4   5                      ACME  http://www.someurl.com  +44123456789
5   6                      acme  http://www.someurl.com  +44123456789
6   7                  CMEA LLC  http://www.someurl.com  +44123456789
7   8                  CMEA lLC  http://www.someurl.com  +44123456789
9  10                     12345  http://www.someurl.com  +44123456789
```

---

**Update**: for the issue columns:

```
# this is no longer needed
# df[duplicates|longtitles|contains|numerics|urls] 

df['issue'] = np.select((duplicates, longtitles, contains, numerics, urls),
                        ('dup', 'longtitles', 'regTitle', 'numeric', 'url'),
                        'invalid')

df = df[df['issue'] != 'invalid']
```

Output:

```
      id  name                      url                            phone  issue
--  ----  ------------------------  ----------------------  ------------  ----------
 0     1  ACME                      http://www.someurl.com  +44123456789  dup
 1     2  http://www.someurl.com    http://www.someurl.com  +44123456789  longtitles
 2     3  longsinglewordname        http://www.someurl.com  +44123456789  longtitles
 3     4  long multiple words name  http://www.someurl.com  +44123456789  longtitles
 4     5  ACME                      http://www.someurl.com  +44123456789  dup
 5     6  acme                      http://www.someurl.com  +44123456789  dup
 6     7  CMEA LLC                  http://www.someurl.com  +44123456789  dup
 7     8  CMEA lLC                  http://www.someurl.com  +44123456789  dup
 9    10  12345                     http://www.someurl.com  +44123456789  numeric
```

Comment: Hi Quang, thank you for your answer this already helps me a lot. However, I need 'contains' to be more precise because at the moment it would mark names like Quincy for INC which is not my intention. The 'urls' you proposed won't work for my scenarios as often I have url without https or even www. but only with .xxx or .xx Also would you be able to help with adding the column 'issue' to each pulled row in new.csv? thanks for your help!

Comment: @Baobab1988 updated with word boundary in `str.contains` and `issue` column.

Comment: Hi, thank you I tried with the 'issue' column but it gives me the following error: `>>> df['issue'] = np.select((duplicates, longtitles, contains, numerics, urls),('dup', 'longtitles', 'regTitle', 'numeric', 'url'),'invalid')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in select
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 705, in select
    'invalid entry {} in condlist: should be boolean ndarray'.format(i))
TypeError: invalid entry 2 in condlist: should be boolean ndarray`